# How to logout from facebook using my php web site

Tags: javascript

How to logout from facebook using my php web site

this function detect as a logout,but my facebook account still not logout

```
<script>
function Logout()
    {
        FB.logout(function () {
            document.location.reload();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Javascript is client side. And Session is server side.

So, using javascript you can't Logout from facebook. because facebook SDK's function sometimes doesn't terminate user session.
So best practice is in your file put `session_destroy()` function if you want to destroy all the session variables or simply use `print_r($_SESSION)` and find out the session variables of facebook and unset those variable using `unset($foo);` if want to continue other session variable.